# What can i use instead of Display Flex to support in IE9

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Here's  [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/qyroxexv/21/)

I want to change the order of 2nd and 3rd element in mobile screen with the css. What Will be best way of doing it.

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="a">image</div>
<div id="b">button</div>
<div id="c">description</div>
</div>
```

Css

```
  @media screen and (max-width:300px){
  #parent{
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: column;
   }
#a{order:1;}
#c{order:2;}
#b{order:3;}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to have a fallback for flexbox at desktop sizes, but

1) 300px is smaller than any smartphone on the market today

2) There are no phones/tablets/devices that small that run IE9. Last I checked, IE9 only exists as a desktop program.

So if you're targeting small stuff, go ahead and just use flexbox. If you still need a fallback (ie if you plan to use flexbox effects at desktop+ resolutions), there have been [some interesting solutions devised using css display:table](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2013/06/css/css-stacking-with-display-table).